# How to determine what changed a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

I've got two objects bound to the same dependencyProperty (in Silverlight). 
Is there a way to determine which of these two objects changed the property?
I want to take different actions based on that information.

Unfortunately, I cannot attach two different eventHandlers ([because it's a dependencyProperty](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/12/10/5430331.aspx))

```
   public int StartTime
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StartTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartTimeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartTime", typeof(int), typeof(Step),
        new PropertyMetadata(-1, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStartTimeChanged)));

    private static void OnStartTimeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Step)d).OnStartTimeChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnStartTimeChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if set from obj1 -> do something
        //if set from obj2 -> do something else
    }
```

In this example I would be setting StartTime property from different objects and I want to know which of these object changed the property.

Thanks

Comment: What reason do you need to know which object changed the property?  If this is required, it sounds like the requirements are a bit incorrect.  Your control should not be involved in these sort of decisions.

Comment: well, it's a long story. The property can be changed from the server (the same property is also bound to the user interface). if the property was changed by the server it should update UI, if the property was changed by the user (by interaction with the UI) it should send update to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ended up catching a mouseDown event on the control so I knew the value of a dependencyProperty was changed by the user interface. It is not the cleanest solution but it worked.

Many thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- look at the sender in the event handler
- attach both controls to different event handlers

Comment: I have updated the question as probably it wasn't descriptive enough.

Answer (score -1):

```
var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(YourType.StartTimeProperty , tpeof(YourType));
descriptor.AddValueChanged(obj1, OnStartTimeChanged1);
descriptor.AddValueChanged(obj2, OnStartTimeChanged2);
```

Comment: DependencyPropertyDescriptor is not available in SL.